# Is a labour union formally different to a one-off (or infrequent) grassroots collective negotiation?

Tags: trade-unions

Are labour unions categorically different from a one-off (or infrequent) grassroots negotiation occurring between workers and bosses?

Comment: Different in what way? Do you mean from economic perspective or legal perspective? Trivially they are not legally equivalent. Economically they could be equivalent if they have the same economic effect

Comment: I was wondering if there were innate characteristics that distinguished trade unions from a ad-hoc grassroots collective action.

Comment: but that was clear, what is not clear what sort of difference you are talking about. For example, from physics perspective there is no innate difference between live and non-live matter if it is composed of the same atoms from biological perspective there is difference. From economic perspective label you give something such as “grassroot movement” is irrelevant but from legal standpoint it isn’t